# rails content_tag nav builder helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, content-tag

Sorry if this sounds obvious but i'm getting confused.
I'm trying to build a navigation list helper.

At the moment it receives a list of links from an array.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def site_pages
    %w{index about contact promotions}
  end

  def nav_builder list     
    list.map do |l|
      content_tag :li do
        content_tag :a, :href => "#{l}_path" do
          l
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But when I run the page it ouput everything is the page as an array.

```
[<li><a href="index_path">index</a></li> <li><a href="about_path">about</a></li> <li><a href="contact_path">contact</a></li> <li><a href="promotions_path">promotions</a></li>]
```

instead of displaying a list of links.
Is there anything special to do?

==EDIT==

I call my builder this way:

```
<%= nav_builder site_pages %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The helper is expected to return a String of HTML, rather than an Array. Try joining the Array elements into a single String:

```
def nav_builder list     
  list.map do |l|
    content_tag :li do
      content_tag :a, :href => "#" do
        "test"
      end
    end
  end.join("\n").html_safe
end
```

Comment: When I do that, stil get the all thing printed as a string on screen. It doesn't translate it as html, so i en dup with <ul>"<li>...</li>"</ul>

Comment: You should replace `join("\n)` with `join("\n").html_safe` to avoid HTML to be escaped.

Comment: Oops, little detail, it doesn't convert the "#{l}_path" (ex about_path). result is <a href="about_path"></a>

Comment: But it works if i run it through a hash, {:home => "/", :about => "/about", :contact => contact_path}...